# Unable to call xcodebuild on project created by cordova

Tags: xcode, cordova-2.0.0

Just started using Xcode4.5. Created a project using Apache cordova ios (2.1.0), using "create" script of cordova. I am unable to call "xcodebuild" on the project generated this way. It gives error saying file "Cordova/CDVViewController.h" not found.

At this point, "xcodebuild -list" shows only 1 schema "CordovaLib". Next I open the myproject.xcodeproj in Xcode and then close xcode (without doing anything). But once opened in Xcode, "xcodebuild -list" shows 2 schemas: "CordovaLib" and "myproject". And now running "Xcodebuild -schema myproject" works fine!

I need to be able to get xcodebuild without opening the project in Xcode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
abbas

Comment: Check whether your project scheme is shared, it need to be shared